# Angular Bootstrap - ngbDatepicker - Convert selected Date into Date Object

Tags: angular, date, data-conversion, ng-bootstrap, ngb-datepicker

in form, for date field using angular bootstrap - `ngbDatepicker`

```
<input  ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" [readonly]="true"
                            [minDate]="{year: 1900, month: 1, day: 1}"
                            [formControl]="empForm.controls['dob']" />
```

and the date is.
[image]

Here trying to create a Date Object, to replace the employee form date.
But getting a DIFFERENT Date

```
let oDob = new Date(employeeToSave.dob['year'], employeeToSave.dob['month'],  employeeToSave.dob['day']);
```

Thu Jan 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
the selected date `"2019-12-02"` is now `"2020-01-02"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Date()` indexing of month is **0 based** you whatever number you want to enter like `december(12th month)` will have value `11`. So try putting (month-1) in `new Date()`.

**Like shown below:**

```
let oDob = new Date(employeeToSave.dob['year'], employeeToSave.dob['month']-1,  employeeToSave.dob['day']);
```

**Working snippet :**

```js
let month=12;
let year = 2019;
let day = 12;
dob = new Date(year,month,day);
console.log("wrong Date : "+dob);

dob2 = new Date(year,month-1,day);
console.log("correct Date : "+dob2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify date format by implementing [NgbDateAdapter](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/adapters/ngb-date-adapter.ts) abstract class, but actually, there is a native `Date` adapter out of box.

[See official docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples), you are looking for this line:

```
 providers: [{provide: NgbDateAdapter, useClass: NgbDateNativeAdapter}]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Month-1` and `Day + 1`

```
let oDob = new Date(employeeToSave.dob['year'], employeeToSave.dob['month'] - 1, employeeToSave.dob['day'] + 1);
```

Comment: You have to add some comments to your answer to make it more helpful.